# Transform specific fields into array(s) using jq

Tags: arrays, json, object, jq

Given the following JSON:

```json
{
  "one": "1",
  "two": "2",
  "flag": "f1 f2 f3",
  "test one": "",
  "test two": "",
  "test three": ""
}
```

Is it possible to obtain the following result using *jq*?

```json
{
  "one": "1",
  "two": "2",
  "flags": ["f1", "f2", "f3"],
  "tests": ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```

Three points are crucial:

1. Leave unchanged any field that is not `flag` or starts with `test`
2. Transform `flag` (space separated values) into an array
3. Any field that starts with `test`  is added to an array (`tests`) where the value is the remaining part of the field's name

Comment: jq is not for this , it is for a search

Comment: @Serge `jq` is perfectly appropriate for a task like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/=` to update by splitting, `startswith` to match at the beginnning of a string, and `to_entries` and `with_entries` to manipulate entries involving the key name:

```sh
jq '
  .flag /= " "
  | .tests = (to_entries | map(.key | select(startswith("test "))[5:]))
  | with_entries(select(.key | startswith("test ") | not))
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_9jFrSXXA3)

---

Another, maybe more efficient implementation which loops just once through the object using `reduce` could be:

```sh
jq '
  reduce to_entries[] as {$key, $value} (null;
    if   $key == "flag"             then .flag = $value / " "
    elif $key | startswith("test ") then .tests += [$key[5:]]
    else                                 .[$key] = $value end
  )
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/NY-xEfFekT)

---

Given the sample data, both produce:

```json
{
  "one": "1",
  "two": "2",
  "flag": [
    "f1",
    "f2",
    "f3"
  ],
  "tests": [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!